# Run heavy script in background using worker threads in Meteor

Tags: node.js, multithreading, meteor, worker

I am using Meteorjs

I have one heavy query which I need to run in background

e.g:

```
Meteor.users.update({}, {$set:{status: 1}});
```

I need this query to run in background.

For that I used worker threads.

I created a worker (when my server launches in config.js):

```
Meteor.startup(function () {

    workerThread  = Npm.require('worker_threads');
    worker        = new workerThread.Worker('worker.js');
});
```

Contents of worker.js:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    
    Meteor.users.update({}, {$set:{status: 1}});
});
```

The above code gives me an error:

```
ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined
```

Does anyone have idea how can I run a background task in Meteorjs?